# Cross-Compiling wxWidgets code from Linux to Windows

Tags: c++, linux, cross-compiling, wxwidgets

I use Code::Blocks IDE with wxWidgets in Debian 8.9 Jessie (x86-64).
When I use the GNU GCC Compiler everything works fine thus compiling nice wxWidgets executable for Linux.
But I need to have my program working on Windows platforms so I have to do cross-compiling.
I have installed mingw32 and followed the cross-compiling instructions given 
[here](http://wiki.codeblocks.org/index.php/Cross_Compiling_wxWidgets_Applications_on_Linux).
I did my wxWidgets build configuration as follows:

```
./configure prefix=/usr/i686-w64-mingw32 --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --enable-unicode --build=`./config.guess` --disable-shared
```

This is so because the MinGW compiler I have is `i686-w64-mingw32`, located in the folder `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32`, and wxWidgets version is 3.1.
My compiler set-up in Code::Blocks should be correct because I managed to do cross-compiling for simple console applications and those run properly on Windows 10.0. But when it comes to wxWidgets applications there are several problems:

1. The compiler gives me the error (it happens when --static is added to `Other compiler options` in the build options for the project):

   ```
   fatal error: wx/app.h: No such file or directory|
   ```

   Now since wx directory in question is in the path `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wx-3.1` I added this path to the search directories for the project (the build target only for the moment). This worked fine to proceed further.
   My compiler settings are: `wx-config --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --static --cflags`
2. The compiler swears again (not surprised though :-)):

   ```
   fatal error: wx/setup.h: No such file or directory|
   ```

   Ok I've found this one in `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/wx/include/i686-w64-mingw32-msw-unicode-static-3.1`, so added this path to the compiler search directories.
3. The linker is swearing this time (creeping on my nerves):

   for the build target:

   ```
   undefined reference to `wxEntry(HINSTANCE__*, HINSTANCE__*, char*, int)'|
   ```

   for the release target:

   ```
   undefined reference to `wxAppConsoleBase::CheckBuildOptions(char const*, char const*)'|
   ```

   My linker settings are `wx-config --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --static --libs`

I tried hard to fix this with several different build options for the wxWidgets library but with no effect on the result. So please, someone help!

I also noticed that running `./config.guess` form the wxWidgets download directory gives me `x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`. Thus this mean I should use `x86_64-w64-mingw32` (I have this one installed in `/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32`) compiler instead `i686-w64-mingw32`?

Comment: Why do you want to cross compile, rather than building directly on Windows (with mingw?)

Comment: I think you will find it much easier to have a Windows machine (possibly a VM) for development and testing purposes.

Comment: @MartinBonner For sure it will be easier, but I don't want to pay for license or do some illegal stuff :-).

Comment: @Pekov, what is the result of running `wx-config --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --libs`? Also, can you successfully build and run minimal sample?

Comment: @Pekov, also, I would try to find an extra machine with Windows installed and try it out. Or just go by a brand new machine.

Comment: @Pekov, try to add that to PATH and recompile the application. Also, did you try `minimal` sample?

Comment: @Igor When I do `make` in the minimal directory of samples from the dowloaded source it generates minimla.exe, which can be opened with wine. When I do `wine niminal.exe` it says `err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll` but it's not a problem just should be linked statically I think. When I use only the minimal.cpp file in a code::blocks project it cannot compile due to the same error as above!

Comment: @Pekov, then just look what command `minimal` sample executes during the build and see if you can replicate it inside C::B. But as `Martin Bonner` and myself said it would be much easier to compile and debug it natively. You will most likely have issues with porting and you will need to debug it which is pane when you need to switch OSes.

Comment: Also, keep in miond that not everything can be seen in Wine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the main issue is that the command `wx-config --static --cflags` is not recognized in `Other compiler options` and `wx-config --static --libs` is not recognized in `Other linker options`.

The problem persisted even though I added the path to wx-config file in the `.bashrc` file from the home directory, i.e. `export PATH="$PATH:/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin"`. At that time I was able to run wx-config from the terminal at any location.

To solve it I've changed the options to `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config --static --cflags` in `Other compiler options` and `/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/bin/wx-config --static --libs` in `Other linker options`. This worked as a charm.

I've added the location of `libstdc++-6.dll` (simply found it with a search in the file manager) in `Link libraries` and the flags `-static` and `-static-libgcc` in `Other linker options` and finally did the testing with the minimal sample as Igor suggested. Just create new console application, add `minimal.cpp` file to it and all of the mentioned above.

The compiler did a `Minimal.exe` file that I have opened successfully with wine.

Note: All the include directories I mentioned in my question were in `wx-config --cflags` for the compiler and `wx-config --libs` for the linker, so no need to add them in search directories.

Comment: you should use ` (backticks) when typing the command in the "Other compiler options". I.e.: `(backtick)wx-config --cxxflags(backtick)`. If those commands without backticks are successfully executed from the Terminal, then you should use backticks in the C::B options dialog. Then everything will be good. Also, make sure that there is no other wx installed on the system as you added the PATH to wx-config at the end to the PATH variable in you .bashrc.

Comment: do you have another wxWidgets installed/compiled? My guess is that it picks up the one you already installed on the system, and since you put the PATH to this one at the end the system will never finds it. Try to run the `wx-config --cxxflags` from the terminal and see what the output is.

Comment: @Igor The output from terminal is: `-I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/lib/wx/include/i686-w64-mingw32-msw-unicode-static-3.1 -I/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/include/wx-3.1 -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64 -D__WXMSW__ -mthreads`. I think thats correct for the `i686-w64-mingw32` compiler. But appears you are right, Synaptic shows me another version of wxWidgets installed, namely `libwxgtk3.0-0` which appears to be installed along with the C::B I think (not sure about it), probably this is the bug!

Comment: this is not a bug. C::B uses its own version of wxWidgets and it installs it alone with C::B. Try to put the path to you wx-config first and not last in PATH env variable. Don't forget to remove it when you are done.